# how to get http request detail in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have an http client request like this?

```
        try {
           $request = json_encode($data);
           $result = $this->pendingRequest->{$method}('http://test.local/general/wallets/1000000', $data);
           // this is my request detail
           $request = $result->transferStats ? Message::toString($result->transferStats->getRequest()) : $request;
           $result->throw();
           $this->setLog($provider, $step, $request, $result->body(), $url, $result->status());
           return $result;
         } catch (RequestException $exception) {
          // I need to http request detail            
         } catch (ConnectionException $exception) {
          // I need to http request detail
         }
```

I need to get my request param and headers and token and every thing that send to third party in cache exceptions. I can get detail in try via: `Message::toString($result->transferStats->getRequest())`

Answer (score 0):

you can @dd($request);
on blade OR
dd($request); on controllers etc..

Answer (score -1):

[Illuminate\Http\Client\Request](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Http/Client/Request.html)

[headers() : array](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Http/Client/Request.html#method_header)

- Get the request headers.

[parameters() : array](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Http/Client/Request.html#method_parameters)

- Get the request's form parameters.

[body() : string](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Http/Client/Request.html#method_body)

- Get the body of the request.

[data() : array](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Http/Client/Request.html#method_data)

- Get the request's data (form parameters or JSON).

Comment: all of this writed in laravel documents. I need to an code like this: `Message::toString($result->transferStats->getRequest())`. Have you ever used this code?

Comment: @mohammadnabipour , Are you referring to accessing the `$request` variable in the `catch...` block?

Comment: The question is for a Http Client request and not a received Http Request

Answer (score -1):

You can take it as

```
$request->all();
```

if you want to see more regular. you can try

```
dd($request->all());
```